# Using static class variables -- in a heredoc

Tags: php, html

I set up a class, which simplified is this:

```
class Labels {
    static public $NAMELABEL = "Name";
}
```

I successfully got the following code to work fine:

```
echo '<table border="1">';
  echo '<tr>';
  echo "<th>" . Labels::$NAMELABEL . "</th>";
  echo '</tr>';

 // the rest of the Table code not shown for brevity...

echo "</table>";
```

I see a table with a column header called **Name** when I run this -- so it works fine.

But not inside a heredoc -- I get "Notice: Undefined variable: NAMELABEL in C:\xampp........blah blah"
when I run the following:

```
    echo <<<_END
       <form action="index.php" method="post"><pre>
       Labels::$NAMELABEL : <input type="text" name="author" />
       <input type="submit" value="ADD RECORD" />
    </pre></form>
_END;
```

I've tried all sorts of quoting, string concat operator '.', nothing works.
I figured "Well I got the static class variables to work in an HTML table, 
why *not* a heredoc."

Dang I love heredocs, they come with a weird name and weird problems.
It's the sort of mind-bending kind of fun I crave, heredocs are 
righteous little doosh monkeys.

I really want to use my static class variables here --  is there some combination
of quoting/string concatenation that will allow me to embed them into my heredocs?

Comment: Which version of PHP are you running, 5.3 or an earlier version?

Comment: This is a long standing bug in the Heredoc parser (scope issue).  I ran across this today while searching for information on a related static variable heredoc parsing bug.

Answer (score 14):

Interpolation in heredocs works the same as in double quotes, so you can use [curly brace ("complex") syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex).

However the parser does not recognize static class variables (see previous documentation).  In order to refer to static class variables, you will need to set them locally as follows:

```
$label = Labels::$NAMELABEL;

echo <<<_END
    <form action="index.php" method="post"><pre>
       $label : <input type="text" name="author" />
       <input type="submit" value="ADD RECORD" />
    </pre></form>
_END;
```

Comment: @Jordan why is the $ necessary, will it work without it.  Some of the examples in the doc you referenced do stuff like `{$foo->$bar}`, and `{${beers::softdrink}}`.  So would `{Labels::$NAMELABEL}`, without the $, work too?

Comment: Thanks, that got me close -- in order to clear a 'bad syntax' warning in my Netbeans editor though, I had to have a space, like this:  ${ Labels::$NAMELABEL }  -- that cleared the syntax error in the browser. Now it evaluates to Name but the browser flags it saying Notice: Undefined variable: Name in C:\xampp.........blah blah.

Comment: I believe there must be a `$` either directly preceding or immediately following the opening `{`. Since `Labels` is a class name in your code (no `$`) you must use `${` so the interpreter knows what to do.

Comment: Oh, it seems that PHP has problems when using static class variables with string interpolation, even with curly brace syntax. There is a note about it in the documentation after the code example in the link above. I've updated my code to show an unfortunately necessary workaround.

Comment: Not flying -- Netbeans is color-coding the syntax correctly but when Labels::$NAMELABLE evaluates to Name its an error.  I tried single quotes, double quotes, I tried the $ inside and outside the brace, tried nested braces, somehow I suspect this heredoc syntax will not work with static class variables, maybe.  I'm going to take a wild guess and suspect that inside the <<< of the heredoc you cannot use variables, only html.

Comment: Read the documentation, wantTheBeast. Heredoc definitely supports variable interpolation. Double-check your code to see that it matches my (updated) code above.

Comment: Thanks for hanging Jordan, bummer that I set out to specifically avoid having to declare a variable just before the heredoc only to then immediately use it in the inline code that immediately follows the variable, maybe they'll fix this in the future.  It's the sort of syntax that your boss, who doesn't know PHP and is threatened by your skills, chides you 'hey, why did you declare variable just a couple lines above more inline code' then you have to be careful you don't snap at him "Because that's the way it works" because he's writing your performance review.  I've had bosses like that.