# How to insert static class properties into a string?

Tags: php, variables, static

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP static variables in double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267093/php-static-variables-in-double-quotes)
>   [Using static class variables — in a heredoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288452/using-static-class-variables-in-a-heredoc)

In PHP you can directly insert a variable into a string (1), and for complex variables you have to enclose them in curly braces (2). This is nice & concise notation, and I use it all the time. But if you want to insert a static class variable into a string, this won't work (3). You have to take the more verbose route and use the "." operator to paste the strings together (4). When you're building a complex string this quickly gets very hard to follow.

I could swear I heard recently that current versions of PHP (~5.3) allow you to use {{}} to insert static class variables into a string, which would still be quite readable. But (5) and (6) are the only permutations that I found that don't give me a syntax error or warning, and as you can see these don't substitute the variables into the string.

Is this possible somehow?

```
$simplevar = 'simple';

class myclass
    {
    public static $prop = 'static-prop';
    }

print "1. before $simplevar after<p>";

print "2. before {$simplevar} after<p>";

print "3. before {myclass::$prop} after<p>";

print "4. before " . myclass::$prop . " after<p>";

print "5. before {{myclass::$prop}} after<p>";

print "6. before {${myclass::$prop}} after<p>";
```

Output:

```
1. before simple after

2. before simple after

3. before {myclass::} after

4. before static-prop after

5. before {{myclass::}} after

6. before after
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267093/php-static-variables-in-double-quotes too (better even, perhaps)

Comment: I guess you're right. Thanks for the links.