# How can I expand a static class variable from within a PHP heredoc expression?

Tags: php, static-members, heredoc

I'm trying to get a static class variable to expand/resolve inside of a [HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) expression within a class constructor, but I cannot find a way to make it work. Please see my very simplified example below:

```
class foo {

  private static $staticVar = '{staticValue}';

  public $heredocVar;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->heredocVar = <<<DELIM
    The value of the static variable should be expanded here: {self::$staticVar}
DELIM;
  }
}

// Now I try to see if it works...
$fooInstance = new foo;
echo $fooInstance->heredocVar;
```

Which results in the following output:

```
The value of the static variable should be expanded here: {self::}
```

Additionally, I've tried various methods to reference the static variable without luck. I'm running PHP version 5.3.6.

---

**Edit**

As pointed out by Thomas, it is possible to use an instance variable to store a reference to the static variable, and subsequently use *that* variable inside the HEREDOC. The following code is ugly, but it does work:

```
class foo {

  private static $staticVar = '{staticValue}';

  // used to store a reference to $staticVar
  private $refStaticVar;

  public $heredocVar;

  public function __construct() {
    //get the reference into our helper instance variable
    $this->refStaticVar = self::$staticVar;

    //replace {self::$staticVar} with our new instance variable
    $this->heredocVar = <<<DELIM
    The value of the static variable should be expanded here: $this->refStaticVar
DELIM;
  }
}

// Now we'll see the value '{staticValue}'
$fooInstance = new foo;
echo $fooInstance->heredocVar;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6288470/1264367)?

I would set `$myVar = self::$staticVar;` and then use `$myVar` in the HEREDOC code.

Comment: No one claimed it to be nifty. ;-)

Comment: I would say it's no more crufty than using `private static` class properties :)